# "Qualcosa di migliore/peggiore" sono forme ammissibili per esprimere "qualcosa di meglio/peggio"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives

So che si dice "niente di meglio" e "niente di peggio". Per esempio, al numero 6 della [voce "meglio" del dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/meglio) si trova:

> **6.** agg.inv. **FO**
>   con valore neutro indica cosa migliore: *se stai calmo è meglio*, *penso sia meglio non dirgli niente* | con il verbo *essere* sottinteso: *meglio, tanto meglio per noi!*, siamo noi che ci guadagnamo | preceduto da *di* in espressioni partitive: *in mancanza di meglio*, *non c’è niente di meglio che un buon caffè*

E al numero 5 della [voce "peggio"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/peggio) dello stesso dizionario si può leggere:

> **5.** agg.inv. **FO** 
>   con valore neutro indica cosa peggiore: *se ti arrabbi è peggio*, *pensavo fosse peggio non dirgli niente* | con il verbo *essere* sottinteso: *peggio, tanto peggio per voi!*, siete voi che ci rimettete; *tanto peggio tanto meglio*, per indicare in modo disfattistico gli aspetti positivi che possono derivare dall’aggravarsi della situazione | in loc.pragm., *peggio che peggio, peggio che mai*, per indicare una condizione estremamente spiacevole o un problema di difficile soluzione | preceduto da *di* in espressioni partitive: *c’è di peggio*, *non poteva succedere niente di peggio*

Tenendo conto delle spiegazioni precedenti che fanno riferimento a espressioni partitive con "meglio" e "peggio", penserei che si debba anche dire "qualcosa di meglio" e "qualcosa di peggio". E, infatti, alla [voce "meglio" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/meglio) appare questo esempio:

> *bisognerebbe cercare qualcosa di meglio*.

Tuttavia, ricercando "qualcosa di migliore" e "qualcosa di peggiore" su Google o su Google Libri, ne trovo molte occorrenze. Allora, la mia domanda sarebbe: sono ammissibili entrambe le forme?

Comment: Con “qualcosa di” si può usare un aggettivo.

Comment: Ma, @egreg: "meglio" e "peggio" col valore che riguarda la domanda sono anche aggettivi  (l'ho aggiunto al mio post).

Comment: Appunto. Dov'è il problema?

Comment: @egreg: Non capisco il senso del tuo primo commento: tanto "migliore" come "meglio" (in questo uso) sono aggettivi. Cioè, il senso sarebbe che dopo "qualcosa di" si può scrivere qualsiasi aggettivo e, per questa ragione, tanto "meglio" come "migliore" vanno bene?

Comment: Non capisco l'obiezione. Ci va un aggettivo: *migliore* è aggettivo, *meglio* può essere usato come aggettivo. Da parte mia direi *qualcosa di meglio*.

Comment: Non c'è nessuna obiezione, @egreg: semplicemente non avevo capito.

Comment: Davvero il DeMauro scrive "guadagnamo" senza la *i*?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/sul-digramma-gn-e-sulla-presenza-della-i-in-forme-verbali-come-guadagniamo/155

Comment: @charo La Crusca dice, giustamente, "omettere quella *i* significa "tagliare" una parte del morfema flessivo"; poi prosegue con "la norma oggigiorno è relativamente elastica". Ognuno può intepretare a modo suo quel *relativamente*: io lo intepreto come restrittivo e ritengo che un dizionario dovrebbe fare altrettanto.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Non credo sia qualcosa da discutere nei commenti a una domanda che non ha niente a che vedere, ma mi sembra un buon argomento per porre un'altra domanda.

Comment: @egreg: Con la funzione "ricerca in sequenza" del [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI10/GDLI_10_ocr_778.pdf) sono riuscita a trovare: «Locuz. – *Avere  monca  ogni  speranza  di meglio*: essere convinto di non  poter trovare niente di migliore».

Comment: E [anche](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI13/GDLI_13_ocr_334.pdf): «*Quello che offre la  piazza*: la merce che è possibile reperire in una certa località (e ha per lo più connotazione spreg., sottintendendo che  non se ne può trovare di migliore)» (non so cosa succede che non funzionano i JPG del GDLI). Se si può usare "migliore" in queste espressioni, immagino si possa anche dire "qualcosa di migliore".